# Reading data from file into a struct (C)

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc, fread

Sorry if this formatting is messy this is my first time using stackoverflow. 
I am trying to use the `fread` function to read into the `card.raw` file in blocks of 512 bytes and store the first 4 bytes of the block into `s1-s4` and the other 508 bytes left over into the array of bytes. However, when I try to run this I get a segmentation fault. When I tried debugging, after the `fread` function is called, `argv`, `outptr`, `inptr`, and `buf` values all become `NULL`. Why is that and what am I doing wrong?

```
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

//block of 512 bytes
typedef struct 
{
    BYTE s1;
    BYTE s2;
    BYTE s3;
    BYTE s4;
    BYTE image[508];
}
BUFFER;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //opens memory card file
    FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");

    int jpgcounter = 0;

    //creates jpg file
    char title[7];
    sprintf(title, "%d.jpg", jpgcounter);
    FILE* outptr = fopen(title, "a");

    //create buf (pointer) of type BUFFER
    BUFFER* buf;

    do
    {
        //creates buffer structure for storage of 512B blocks 
        buf = malloc(sizeof(BUFFER));

        //read 512 bytes at a time & stores every 512B block into a buffer struct buf
        fread(&buf, sizeof(BUFFER), 1, inptr);

        if(buf->s1 == 0xff && buf->s2 == 0xd8 && buf->s3 == 0xff)
        {
```

The if statement is used to check if the first 3 elements of `buf` contain the following hexadecimal signatures. I wanted to use `malloc` in a loop in order to read the raw file in structs of 512 bytes, decide what to do with the 512 bytes, then free it continuously.

Comment: Do you want to read the data into the variable `buf`, or into the memory block that `buf` holds a pointer to?

Comment: `fread(&buf, sizeof(BUFFER), 1, inptr);` --> `fread(buf, sizeof(BUFFER), 1, inptr);`

Comment: 1st of all add error checking to `fopen()` and `fread()`. As it stand the code does not take any actions on testing whether accessing the file worked at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use   `fread(buf, sizeof(BUFFER), 1, inptr);` instead of   `fread(&buf, sizeof(BUFFER), 1, inptr);` Also open file in binary mode to read i.e. `"rb"` instead of `"r"`

Comment: Thank you! But why open the file in binary mode exactly?

Comment: Some system may treat `"r"` and `"rb"` mode differently. For example line ending could be handled differently. Your data seems to be pure binary where you would not want that system manipulate it while reading hence it's safe to open it in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `&buf` pointer instead of `buf` into the `fread` function it will write your data not in the allocated heap buffer, but on your function stack. Since stack on `x86` platforms grows towards the lower memory addresses, this will overwrite everything on the stack, that was before your `buf` variable - in your case a local variables, function arguments `argc`, `argv`, etc and return address. Stack became corrupted and you get a segmentation fault.